# Binary Data with Count Dependent Variable?

Tags: r, regression, multiple-comparisons, binary-data, poisson-regression

Howdy internet strangers!

I've put a sample of my data below, but basically I have the number of accidental falls in a particular set of patients vs. drugs that the patients were taking. The drugs they were taking are coded in a binary manner - 1 if they were on the drug, 0 if they were not. Any ideas on how to analyze this data?

The question I would like answered is "Do patients on drug X have an increased risk of falling?" And an risk ratio for each drug would also be great.

I have an engineering background and can run scripts in R but I am by no means a statistic expert. I was doing GLM with Poisson regression (in R) for each drug, but I have an inkling this is the wrong test to be doing. I would like to use some sort of multiple comparisons (that takes into account all of the drugs that each individual patient was on) but I don't know what test is most appropriate. Thank you in advance for your help!

[image: Sample Data]

Answer (score 1):

Gabe, welcome to the site!

I'll try to give you some answers and some clarifications so that you can dig deeper.

- First of all, your dependent variable (# of falls) is not continuous it is discrete, despite having infinitely many values that it can take.
- Second (and most importantly) of all, Poisson regression was not a bad idea at all and might be the best way to go.  One import consideration is *how long each patient has been on the drugs*.  The parameter being estimated in Poisson Regression is a *rate*, how many times we expect an event to happen over a fixed period of time.  Poisson regression can take this into account with something called **exposure**, which I suggest you look into.
- You talked about comparing an increase in fall *risk*, which makes it sound like a binary event (fall or no fall) versus a count event (how many times will they fall).  Do you want a risk instead of a rate?  If so you might want to consider dichotomizing the result and trying logistic regression, though personally I think the Poisson regression is preferable.
- Lastly, if you don't have a lot of data, you might want to consider **Bayesian** methods and/or reducing the number of questions you're trying to answer.

Hope this was helpful and gave you enough to keep digging.  Let me know if you have follow-ups.